# Add a variable in front of values of certain columns in a CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, powercli

I'am currently trying to create a simple `Import-Csv` to clone vm-guests from a template to a esx host in vcenter.

Before I start the cloning I want to ask for the name of the site the vm-guests will belong to. The name of the site is part of the name the vm-guest will have, and also part of the foldername, the guest will be put into.

```
Connect-VIServer -Server vcenter.localdomain.com -user *

$Site = Read-Host "What is the name of the Site you want to install (i.e. Site01)?"

Import-Csv "C:\guests.csv" -UseCulture | %{
New-vm -Name  $_."Server Name" -VMhost $_."ESX Host" -Template $_.Template -Datastore $_.Datastore  -Location $_.Folder
}
```

How/Where do I put in the variable `$Site` to have it in front of `$_."Server Name"` and `$_.Folder`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a *format string*:

```
Connect-VIServer -Server vcenter.localdomain.com -user *

$Site = Read-Host "What is the name of the Site you want to install (i.e. Site01)?"

Import-Csv "C:\guests.csv" -UseCulture | %{
New-vm -Name ('{0}{1}' -f $Site, $_."Server Name") -VMhost $_."ESX Host" -Template $_.Template -Datastore $_.Datastore  -Location ('{0}{1}' -f $Site, $_.Folder)
}
```